# Iterate through items in list within dict in python

Tags: list, dictionary

Please help me with basics of dict.

I have a dict which has value as a list  below:

```
test = {2:['a',2,4,6], 3:[1,2,4,8]}
```

i need to get value with index[0] in k==2

output must be 'a'

Answer (score 0):

Really simple:

```
test[2][0]
```

If you are a beginner you should check out the python docs for information on dict access.